# Flutter Firebase Messaging 'MismatchSenderId' error when using Postman?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I'm using the `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` api to send a push notification. I keep getting this error when trying to send a push notification using Postman:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 7660095333537950368,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "MismatchSenderId"
        }
    ]
}
```

I definitely have the right Cloud Messaging server key in the Header Authorization with the value `key={{firebase server key}}`. I'm posting to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` this 'raw' 'json' body:

```
{
    "to" : "AAAAr4-T02k:APA91bHicpacJ2tyn_XGcfRX3BnhkJSmyzWp-the-rest-of-my-server-key",
    "priority": "high",
    "data" : {
        "content": {
            "id": 1,
            "channelKey": "mass",
            "title": "Huston! The eagle has landed!",
            "body": "A small step for a man, but a giant leap to Flutter's community!"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Flutter. I have the google-services.json in the root of the 'app' folder inside of the 'android' folder.

I've seen in other posts people say to check to make sure your server key matches in the google-services.json file. I don't see a server key in the google-services.json file. I do see a `project_number` that matches the `sender_id` in my Firebase Cloud Messaging settings. Should the google-services.json file also have a server_key somewhere?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your message body "to" field is for device registration token, not server key, see [Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref).

> The value can be a device's registration token, a device group's notification key, or a single topic (prefixed with /topics/)

Comment: What "to" value do I use to send a notification to all of the apps subscribed to this Firebase app? So to send a notification to all app users?

Comment: And how do I get the 'device registration token'?

Comment: There doesn't exists "to" value for all. There several ways to send for a bigger audience, see [Send messages to multiple devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple).  A register token is retrieved by an application and then send to a server, see [Retrieve the current registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#retrieve-the-current-registration-token)